How to find a list of categorical columns that have same values?
I would like to make something like we do to loc() and rows. Though, now I want the columns that have same values. Or, to apply some filter with the unique values to find the columns.
Things that I tried and didn't work:
from itertools import combinations
[(i, j) for i,j in combinations(df, 2) if df[i].equals(df[j])]

Then, I tried nunique:
data.loc[:, data.nunique() < 1].columns

Output: Index([], dtype='object')
I made my lists "manually" using value_counts() to verify which of the columns have the same values. Very likely, there is a "cute", clean, fast way to deliver that with code.
Thanks, in advance.
Best regards,
Richard Levinson
